# Gradle error when building Flutter apk after adding firebase

Tags: firebase, gradle, dart, firebase-cloud-messaging, flutter

I want to implement Firebase Cloud Messaging into my Flutter application and i started to implement the Android part. I added the dependencies just like in the Firebase documentation, but now I'm getting gradle error when building my app:

```
The library com.google.firebase:firebase-iid is being requested by various other libraries at [[16.0.0,16.0.0]], but resolves to 15.1.0. Disable the plugin and check your dependencies tree using ./gradlew :app:dependencies.
```

I'm not experienced at all with gradle, so I would appreciate some help^^

Here is app/build.gradle

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.leodr.pguapp"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.0.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

And here is the project build.gradle(if needed):

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: First thing I can see is that your app/build.gradle is missing `compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.0'`

Comment: that throws up another error when I add it^^: `> The library com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base is being requested by various other libraries at [[15.0.4,15.0.4]], but resolves to 15.0.2. Disable the plugin and check your dependencies tree using ./gradlew :app:dependencies.`

Comment: `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.0'` to `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'` ? I should probably just make a new project to replicate the issue.

Comment: unfortunately that doesn't solve any of the errors :(

Comment: It sounds like a dependency conflict, but not sure what. Ill come back to this one later and try the project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Downgrade the gms version on your build.gradle to

classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.1'

Comment: This can't seriously be the actual solution. I've been battling this issue for weeks, and all anyone seems to say is downgrade google-services...

Answer (score 0):

write this at the bottom of app.gradle `com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin.config.disableVersionCheck = true`

Answer (score 0):

hello I had the same problem but I fixed it by adding in buil.gradle, I hope and solve it

```
dependencies {

    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, when you don't have latest version of GRADLE/SDK/ANDROID STUDIO and you use the latest firebase supports version then this type of error may be generate.

So for the solution you have to decrease the gms version to run with your SDK compatible versoin.